# Travel options from Spain to Gibraltar

Tags: spain, gibraltar

I want to spend one day in Gibraltar during my trip to Spain. What are my travel options?

I shall most probably travel from Barcelona (my landing city) to Gibraltar. I have a preference for economy first.

(This is not about visa requirements).

Comment: Some options here https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Barcelona/Gibraltar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cheapest option might well be plane and bus. I'm seeing prices as low as 46€ one-way from Barcelona to Málaga, and then 13€ for a bus from Málaga to Gibraltar.

For the flight it's worth checking a comparison website: the 46€ price was for a Ryanair flight, but Vueling are also in the region of 50€ on some flights. Prices obviously vary according to time of day and how far in advance you book.

For the bus there's no choice: Avanza is the only option, and there's no price advantage to booking in advance, although there is the benefit of being sure you won't arrive and find that the bus is full.

Note: Málaga is one of the largest airports in Spain, so you should allow plenty of time for the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the train from Barcelona to Algeciras and then either get a bus or taxi. There are more details in the page of the man in Seat 61 [here](https://www.seat61.com/Gibraltar.htm#London_to_Gibraltar). Note that section starts in London ut since it includes an overnight in Barcelona it should be easy enough to pick up the route. Spanish trains are not that expensive but your opinion might vary from mine.

Comment: Scratches head… there is so much to see between Barcelona and Gibraltar. Unless you are on some sort of passport stamp treasure hunt, Granada is one of the most beautiful cities in the world…